# How to get all file and note in yammer using API

Tags: yammer

Is there a way  to get all file uploaded and note in yammer using API?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Data Export API](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api) to get data in bulk from Yammer.

Comment: Thank you so much, so it means I have to use yammer paid not free cause there is no privilege "verif_admin" in basic yammer, my question is does user with privilege verif_admin can have the same role as network_admin like  delete all comments posted in the network?